# Pulling SAP tables into BluePrism

Tags: blueprism

I'm trying to extract an SAP table into BluePrism as a collection. The table is in the default SAP format and in xlsx extension.

I was able to pull a non-SAP table using the following path from Excel VBO:

1. Open Workbook
2. Activate Sheet
3. Get Worksheet as a collection

With the SAP table, using the exact equivalent procedure, I get a blank collection whereas the other table works just fine.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the table for better reference?

Answer (score 0):

We may have an issue with terminology here but, if you are trying to export an SAP table (not a file but a table on an SAP screen or tab page) to a collection, all you need to do is create a business object, spy the table in SAP mode, and create an action page that uses a Read stage with the Get All Items option to export the entire table to a collection. SAP exports the data with column headers and, for some inexplicable reason, SAP developers have a habit of using the same column header text for more than one column in the same table. That will cause the Get ALl Items to fail witha duplicate column names error. If this occurs, you need to set the Data Browser (if the table has one) to display the database field names (guaranteed to be unique) instead of the column headers. In your original post, you state "The table is in the default SAP format and in xlsx extension", which makes me think you may be talking about a file instead of a table. If that is the case, forget about exporting the table to Excel and use what I described above to export from SAP directly into a collection.

Answer (score -1):

You also can use a freeware tool like ExtracTable for SAP from sourceforge.net

It will download the SAP table into Excel and/or CSV format so that you can use RPA like Blueprism to further process.